# Elm to RestDB request CORS blocked

Tags: ajax, cors, elm

I'm having trouble retrieving data from RestDB to my simple Elm app.

### UPDATE I've removed link to the demonstration that has been here previously. Only the problem symptoms description follows.

In the Network tab of the Firefox console, I can see

1. an OPTION request. I do not generate this one programatically, I believe it was generated by the browser itself as part of the CORS protocol handshake
2. an OPTION response with proper access-control-allow-origin
3. the actual GET request,
4. the actual GET response, this time WITHOUT access-control-allow-origin header. @ivarni suggest that this missing header may be the cause of the problem. I'll investigate.

This is an example of the communication:

### 1. `OPTION https://fffuuu-c42f.restdb.io/rest/messages`

Request headers

```
Host: fffuuu-c42f.restdb.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-apikey
Referer: https://dvtomas.github.io/elm-cors/
Origin: https://dvtomas.github.io
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

### 2. Response

```
`{"message":"CORS access granted ok!"}`
```

Response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
access-control-allow-origin: https://dvtomas.github.io
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key, Datatype, apikey, x-apikey, x-pagination, x-api-token, cache-control
access-control-allow-credentials: true
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 37
etag: W/"25-WUI0MQINt5pkY435jKTqrzN4R94"
vary: Accept-Encoding
date: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 06:08:08 GMT
connection: close
```

### 3. `GET https://fffuuu-c42f.restdb.io/rest/messages`

Request header

```
Host: fffuuu-c42f.restdb.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://dvtomas.github.io/elm-cors/
x-apikey: 12745cc133246d659d53960af2463940e69d7
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: https://dvtomas.github.io
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

### 4. Response

```
[
{"_id":"5d4ee4285fde27420000a724","username":"CUser","timestamp":1,"topic":"CTopic","message":"CMessage"},       {"_id":"5d4f21575fde27420000b1fa","username":"u","timestamp":1565466966129,"topic":"t","message":"xxxxx"}
]
```

Response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
surrogate-control: no-store
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip
date: Mon, 12 Aug 2019 06:08:09 GMT
connection: close
transfer-encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Please put all relevant information in the question itself. Stack Overflow is intended more as a knowledge base than a personalized help center, and when those links eventually change or die, both the question and the answers will likely become worthless. See [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: Good job on the demo though, but it should be auxiliary, not instead of a properly formulated question.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you also need to send CORS headers for the actual GET response and not just the response to the OPTION preflight request. When using `curl` against the endpoint I can't see CORS headers in the response, so I would give that a try.

Comment: I've added an example communication with a description. That should make the question work alone without having to use the demo. @ivarni, thank you for the tip, I'll try following that path.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault, I accidentally configured the app to use the RestDB Server API key instead of the CORS one. Thanks go to the RestDB staff for spotting it.